# matlab call explorer with special character issue

Tags: matlab, url

When MATLAB calls Internet Explorer, it looks like it can't process special character `&` correctly. Then I tried to use escape `%26`, but it doesn't help.

Any other ideas?

```
system('start http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ta?s=MSFT&t=1m&l=on&z=l&q=l&p=e5%2Ce10%2Ce20&a=vm&c=')
't' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 
'l' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 
'z' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 
'q' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 
'p' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 
'a' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 
'c' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Windows cmd.exe interprets `&` as the command separator - hence all those `'t' is not recognized...` errors are shown because Windows interprets the character following the `&` as a new command. You need to escape `&` with the `^` character, like so:

```
system('start http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ta?s=MSFT^&t=1m^&l=on^&z=l^&q=l^&p=e5%2Ce10%2Ce20^&a=vm^&c=');
```

Comment: I just can't believe I've got the answer so quickly. Thanks a lot!